# Fetching EntityConnection string from app configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

Some quick questions:

So I have this `LogInWindow` dialog that I use to collect all the SQL login info and then pass the constructed connection string to the `ServiceManager.InitializeContext()` method, which initializes my entities context with a specific provider connection.

It's all working fine. But I would like to initialize the `LogInWindow` dialog with the values that are defined in the App.config configuration file.

Is there a preferred method for doing this initial setup? i.e., should I resort to instantiating a dummy `EntityContext` using the default constructor just for the sheer purpose of fetching the default provider connection? Is there a "cleaner" way?

By the way, would you consider it a "safe" practice to do this type of `Form.Close()` invocation inside a handler to the `Form.Shown` event? I read on MSDN that it is not advisable to call `Form.Close()` inside a handler to the `Form.Load` event.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form {

    private void MainWindow_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (var logInWindow = new LogInWindow()) {
            if (logInWindow.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
                this.serviceManager.InitializeContext(logInWindow.ConnectionString);
            } else {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}


public sealed class ServiceManager : IDisposable {

    public void InitializeContext(string connectionString) {
        if (this.EntityContext != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("EntityContext cannot be initialized multiple times.");

        var entityConnectionString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityConnectionString.ProviderConnectionString = connectionString;
        entityConnectionString.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entityConnectionString.Metadata = "res://*/EntityModel.EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.EntityModel.msl";

        this.EntityContext = new EntityContext(entityConnectionString.ConnectionString);
        this.EntityContext.ObjectMaterialized += EntityContext_ObjectMaterialized;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all parts of your App.config using System.Configuration class

Example:

```
var connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

var stringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);

string UserID = stringBuilder.UserID;
string Password = stringBuilder.Password;
string catalog = stringBuilder.InitialCatalog;
```

App.config

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/...........
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm curious, what type of connection does the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` collection return? A `EntityConnection`? Keep in mind I'm only interested in the **provider connection string** part of it.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a `ConnectionStringSettings`... Problem is, that type does not break the connection string into parts, i.e., the Initial Catalog, Uset ID, Password, etc... I still find using the `ConfigurationManager` useful though.

Comment: I have an application that does exactly what you are tying to do, I just split the connection string to get the Username/password.
There could be a nicer way to do this, but I have found no problems with the hacky way I am doing it :)

Comment: There is a way to do what you want, fixes my implementation too :)
Updated above

Comment: I realize that this is an old answer, but thought it would be helpful for others to know that I've found it not to work with current versions of ADO.Net. When I call the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder()` constructor, it fails with an exception with the message "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."  My connection string is a standard EF connection string - ` <connectionStrings><add name="Development" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BModel.csdl|res://*/BModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data s...." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/></connectionStrings>`